# Loop in range of cells with fixed last row

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I need to loop in a range (in my case column A) to get following results:

```
  A       B
  1   = 2 - 1
  2   = 3 - 1
  3   = 3 - 2
  4   = 4 - 1
  5   = 4 - 2
      = 4 - 3
      = 5 - 1
      = 5 - 2
      = 5 - 3
      = 5 - 4
```

I want number 5 to be deducted by 4, 3, 2 ,1 and then number 4 by 3, 2, 1 and so on.
I was somehow able to achieve this with collection but since dataset is rather big script is running 30+ minutes.

At this point I'm trying to figure out arrays but I don't know how to get desired result. My main concern is whether I can loop from bottom to top (From number 5 to 1, not 1 to 5) and how to fixate last row (fix number 5, conduct deductions and then fix number 4, do math magic and loop to 3 and so on).

My current code is:

```
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim lastc, lastr As Long

lastc = FindColNumber
lastr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, lastc).End(xlUp).Row

Arr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, last), ws.Cells(lastr, lastc))
For i = LBound(Arr, 1) To UBound(Arr, 1) - 1
If (Arr(i, 1) > 0) And (Arr(i + 1, 1) > Arr(i, 1)) Then
Arr(i, 1) = Arr(i, 1) - Arr(i + 1, 1)
```

Code does deduction as following: 5-4, 4-3, 3-2, 2-1 and that's not what I need.

Any tips?

Thank you.

Comment: you need two loops, the second will loop from Lbound to i -1

Comment: You are allowed to loop backwards in VBA.  `For i = 5 To 1 Step -1` and if you want to loop backwards through a range you can do `For i = MyRng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1` and then refer to the individual cells using `MyRng.Cells(i)`

Comment: you will also need a second array to hold the ouputs.

Comment: @Toddleson looping a range is slow.  The OP should remain with variant arrays and bulk assign.

Comment: @ScottCraner My comment was only informing of a possibility, not suggesting it as a solution.

Comment: @Toddleson I'm aware of backward looping but if I want to stick with arrays going For i = UBound(Arr, 1) to LBound(Arr, 1) results in an error.

Thank you.

Comment: @ScottCraner Could you please elaborate how to insert second array for results? Or what exactly do you mean? And why should I loop from LBound to i -1 ?

Thank you.

Comment: @Thayskills you need the `Step -1` part. Like `For i = UBound(Arr, 1) to LBound(Arr, 1) Step -1`. And I was just responding to your question in the post "My main concern is whether I can loop from bottom to top"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you will need two loops and another output array:

```
Sub lkjlkjkdl()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim lastc As Long, lastr As Long
    
    lastc = 1 'FindColNumber
    lastr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, lastc).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Arr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, lastc), ws.Cells(lastr, lastc))
    
    Dim cnt As Long
    cnt = ((UBound(Arr, 1) - 1) * UBound(Arr, 1)) / 2
    
    
    Dim k As Long
    k = 1
    
    Dim outarr As Variant
    ReDim outarr(1 To cnt, 1 To 1)
    
    For i = LBound(Arr, 1) + 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
        Dim j As Long
        For j = LBound(Arr, 1) To i - 1
            outarr(k, 1) = Arr(i, 1) - Arr(j, 1)
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ws.Range("B2").Resize(cnt, 1).Value = outarr
            
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: FYI sum of sequential integers 1-n is `(n*(n+1))/2` so you could skip the first loop

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks, I knew there was one, but was too lazy to find it.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks Scott, works like a charm. Just out of curiosity, is it possible to loop from UBound to LBound? Does an array have this functionality?

Comment: Yes, you would `For i = Ubound(arr,1) to Lbound(arr,1) Step -1`